# Bitcoin arbitrage collection formula

Tags: bitcoin, bitconverter

https://cryptorank.io/price/bitcoin/arbitrage

I am working on displaying the various currencies like Bitcoin arbitrage URL shared above.
There are number of the records with +9.53%, +7.7% against the other currencies. I tried hard to find out the formulae for this calculation but I was unable to do this.

I asked this question if anyone worked on this type of the problem before might helpful for me to get the idea on this.

Looking forward for your suggestions!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The percentages as shown on this page are calculated based on the exchange rates of the row and column (i.e. of different exchanges):

```
1 - (exchangeRateOfRow / exchangeRateOfColumn)
```

E.g. the 11.5% in the first cell of your screenshot:

```
1 - (19,536 / 22,069) = 0.115 = 11.5%
```

I don't want to make any statement about whether these are real arbitrage opportunities.